# When I try to delete some old folders on my mac desktop I get error. I have tried some method but failed. Error is shown in description

Tags: permission, desktop, macos, administrator

I have tried several methods in the past as well.

While reflecting on root of problem initially after purchasing mac I had password set which was forgotten within week so I had to used command R feature to reset password. After That everything is working fine but folders and files shown on below screen are not deleted.

[image]
Figure 1
[image]
Figure 2

When trying to make any changes such as moving, deleting, renaming to shown folder above request pops up for entering admin password. Even after I enter password following error is shown.

[image]
Figure 3

After researching some method to solve this issue I changed the disk permission from other to read and write as shown below in Figure 4 but still same issue mentioned above in picture Figure 1, 2, and 3 is repeated.

[image]
Figure 4

What further I can do to get rid of those files and folders highlighted on fig 1. I am annoyed as they are useless at the moment and I repeatedly have to encounter them.

Comment: How exactly did you "reset the password?"  `Cmd-R` is booting into recovery mode and there's no "password reset option."   Secondly, do you have *ownership* of the files.  Open Terminal and issue the command:  `ls -la ~/Desktop` and post the actual text output to the question (not an image).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing/deleting those files and folders through command line using terminal ?

- Open Terminal
- type `rm -r` followed by <kbd>Space</kbd>
- Drop&Drag the files/folders to be deleted into the Terminal window (so the file path gets inserted)
- Press <kbd>Return</kbd>